# How to check the "if condition" and assign it on the fly? (Python)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-3.6, control-flow

Say, I want to check if my integer is in the return of the first function or not, if not, then go check the second function, and so on. with these functions

```
import time

def a_very_expensive_function_1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [0,1,2]

def a_very_expensive_function_2():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [3,4,5]

# and maybe more functions
# def a_very_expensive_function_3():
#     time.sleep(1)
#     return [6,7,8]
# ...
```

```
my_int = 1


if my_int in a_very_expensive_function_1():
    result = a_very_expensive_function_1() + [10] # I have to call`a_very_expensive_function_1()` 2nd times here
elif my_int in a_very_expensive_function_2():
    result = a_very_expensive_function_2() + [10]
```

You can notice that with this approach, I have to call the first function 2 times, but I don't have to run the 2nd function since the first function is True, (otherwise I have to repeat the 2nd function 2 times just like the first function.)

Now I want to find an alternative, to avoid calling first function 2 times by doing this:

```
my_int = 1

first_list = a_very_expensive_function_1()
second_list = a_very_expensive_function_2()

if my_int in first_list:
    result = first_list + [10] 
elif my_int in second_list:
    result = second_list + [10]
```

Now I don't have to call the first function 2 times anymore, but now I have to call a second function (and so on) prior to checking the condition, which I imagine to scale badly if I have more than 2 functions.

Is there an optimal way to tackle these problems?

PS. I am not sure but I feel like walrus operator(:=) can solve this problem? But since it's relatively new feature and my developing environment (Google Colab) is still using Python 3.6 I would prefer more primitive and conventional way to solve this problem.

EDIT: For anyone curious, on Python 3.8+, here is how to use walrus operator to assign on the fly. Again, right now I prefer a more primitive method rather than using a feature that people still not get used to.

```
import time

def a_very_expensive_function_1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [0,1,2]

def a_very_expensive_function_2():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [3,4,5]

my_int = 1

if my_int in (result := a_very_expensive_function_1()):
    result += [10] 
elif my_int in (result := a_very_expensive_function_2()):
    result += [10] 

print(result)
# [0, 1, 2, 10]
```

EDIT2: Add example for more than 2 functions

Comment: Don't compute `second_list` until you know you need it.

Comment: @ScottHunter that's the problem, I don't know an elegent way to do that. Otherwise I have to call first function 2 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBBasMwEEX3OsV0FYkOIXLaTSDbLHMBY4SpR0QQj4Qkh/r0rmyHtptgraTH/2/EhDHfPB@nyfXBxwzZ9SRERxZa86A4GvoOxMk9yNiBv7LzbLRUJwHlzOF9uhMFqdVCIuUhMtQH1Fg1W6JqW3TED/x8iqzjTjLC3E/PpvURCByvcGVLH85AUv2@nQWeY/Ev8m9MXGCbEpUVXNp7IoTd1eeiH7h72wnRj8ZxLlItRIjlKpffrBihXgWvV4YbgQpFo@Adan1o1DT9AA)

```py
import time

def a_very_expensive_function_1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [0,1,2]

def a_very_expensive_function_2():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [3,4,5]

def find(n, funcs):
    for e in funcs:
        r = e()
        if n in r:
            return r
    assert False, 'Not found!'

my_int = 1

print(find(my_int, [
    a_very_expensive_function_1,
    a_very_expensive_function_2,
]) + [10])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 10]
```

---

If you're uncomfortable with creating a separate helper function (+ `return`) then you can do exactly same thing with inline `for` loop and `break`:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBBDoIwELzvK9YTEBtDUS8mXj36AUMa1G1shLbZFiOvxyKeZY4zszOT9UN8OLsdR9N5xxGj6QjgThob9SIeFL092WBepHRvb9E4q2ReHAATJvMmtEQ@l8WXYYo9W7yUQoqqXgqqloO2Yif2KQi6QRkb8YgSQDtGQpPkr/fPUrFgqATU8wRO0ZTP5Ubjry518KxPuDI1T6A20Mw1IVD62alJjMDs7CJq19v7KgPwnO5zxjVeZFkX4/gB)

```py
import time

def a_very_expensive_function_1():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [0,1,2]

def a_very_expensive_function_2():
    time.sleep(1)
    return [3,4,5]


my_int = 1

for e in [
    a_very_expensive_function_1,
    a_very_expensive_function_2,
]:
    r = e()
    if my_int in r:
        break
else:
    assert False, 'Not found!'

print(r + [10])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 10]
```

Comment: yep this one would work for me, wish there are cleaner ways to do this.

Comment: What do you think is "unclean" about this?

Comment: it is not particularly "unclean", I'm not sure how to say it, I hope there will be ways to accomplish this without creating a helper function and shortcircuiting with the return. also I need to learn using a function as an object more since im quite rusty on that

Comment: @aviisu If you're uncomfortable with creating a separate helper function then you can do exactly same thing with inlining for loop and using `break`, instead of a function with `return`. Look at my just-updated answer, I created part two of my answer where used inline loop instead of helper function. Is it what you want?

Comment: yep, that's also great, thank!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
my_int = 1

first_list = a_very_expensive_function_1()

if my_int in first_list:
    result = first_list + [10] 
else:
    second_list = a_very_expensive_function_2()
    if my_int in second_list:
        result = second_list + [10]
```

Comment: If I have more than 2 functions (say, 5 functions), I think it will look very messy with how nested the condition is.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, can't you just do something like this?

```
my_int = 1

first_list = a_very_expensive_function_1()   
if my_int in first_list:
    result = first_list + [10] 
else:
    second_list = a_very_expensive_function_2()
    if my_int in second_list:
        result = second_list + [10]
```

And if you have more than two expensive functions to call:

```
very_expensive_functions = [
    a_very_expensive_function_1,
    a_very_expensive_function_2,
    a_very_expensive_function_3,
    a_very_expensive_function_4,
    a_very_expensive_function_5
]

my_int = 1

for f in very_expensive_functions:
    f_result = f()
    if my_int in f_result:
        return f_result + [10]
```

Comment: the else condition would nested bady if I have more than 2 functions (say, 5 functions)

Comment: @aviisu if you have more functions then you could resort to a for loop.